# Enable launching setup from another .msi

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I'm using InstallShield Basic MSI project.
While installing the setup I want the main setup will install another small one.
I understand that .msi setup can't execute another .msi one so my question is:
Are there some settings I can use in the small setup ( Create with InstallShield Basic MSI ) that will still enable me that the main setup will launch the small one,
Like create an .exe instead .msi or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

You can install other MSI or some EXE (or even scripts) from a main MSI installation. (But NOT at any time!) For best results you put this directly after `InstallFinalize`. The following can give you an idea how to achive.

[image: Install Finalize]
(Table: InstallExecuteSequence)

[image: Add Custom Action using WISE]
(This Screenshot is from Wise Package Studio, it gives you an idea how to implement)

[image]
(Table: InstallExecuteSequence, after the implementation)

[image]
(Table: CustomAction)

InstallShielt might handle this differently, but the result is the same.
(You could also put the second MSI inside the Binary Table, and reference from there)